# Куча ошибок в PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

изучаю БД и столкнулся с ошибками в PhpMyAdmin, целая портянка
пробовал через разные браузеры открывать - не помогло, нажать игнорировать всё - помогает до следующего обновления страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Помогло обновление OpenServer, видимо там более новая версия PhpMyAdmin была, а старая конфликтовала с версией PHP самого